# Why do 3d model drawn to a RenderTarget appear distorted compared to those drawn directly?

Tags: xna, rendering, spritebatch

I've got a problem drawing a 3D model to a `RenderTarget2D` in XNA 4. When the model is drawn to a render target, and then the render target is later drawn to the screen it appears distorted. (See right image below)

However, if I draw directly to the backbuffer, then everything appears correctly (See left image)

I'm resetting all the states before doing the 3D drawing. (BlendState, DepthStencilState, SamplerStates and RasterizerState)

[image: Example of problem]

This is my draw method. I first draw to the render target. Then I use a spritebatch to draw this to the screen (offset to the right for this example). Finally yfor direct comparison I reset the states again and draw the 3d model a second time directly to the back buffer (using the exact same `DrawModel()` method) and it works fine.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // First set to use a render target.
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_playerBufferRenderTarget);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        // Reset all the states as appropriate for 3d drawing.
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;

        // Draw the model (to the rendertarget)
        DrawModel();

        // Go back to the backbuffer.
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        // Now draw the rendertarget to the screen as a sprite (Offset to the right).
// (This looks wrong)
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque, null, null, null);
        spriteBatch.Draw(_playerBufferRenderTarget, new Vector2(300, 0), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.End();

        // Again, reset the states.
        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;
        GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;

        // Now draw the model again, but this time directly to the back buffer.
// (This works).
        DrawModel();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

I create the `RenderTarger2D` within the `LoadContent()` method.

```
_playerBufferRenderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 800, 500);
```

This is the DrawModel method for reference although this is basically copied directly from an MSDN sample:

```
    private void DrawModel()
    {
        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[_playerModel.Bones.Count];
        _playerModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in _playerModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(90.0f), aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

I've included a link to the [Player.fbx model file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/314831/Player.fbx). Is it possible that this could be caused by something I've done wrong when creating the model.

Comment: Looks like overdraw due to the lack of depth buffer.

Comment: @arul - Spot on. I changed my RenderTarget creation to specify DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8 and it's working perfectly. (Post it as and answer and I'll accept it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like overdraw due to the lack of depth buffer.

You can specify the depth buffer when you create the RenderTarget2D:

```
 = new RenderTarget2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 800, 500, false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8);
```